# Best way to Unit test a repository layer using EF4

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, repository, moq

I have a repository layer which is using EF4, Object context. I now want to do mock testing on my repository, not integration tests...I want to swap my complete repository with something fake. the problem I am having is I have lot of queries with Includes in the queries.
Pls suggest any good articles in MVC3....

Comment: Show public interface of your repository.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have following layers:
 Controller -> Services -> Repositories

You said you have lot of queries which suppose to be put in the repository classes. To test these queries, integration tests are suitable. To Unit test Services you can use any mock framework like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [Rhino Mock](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks.ashx) to create mock objects of Repositories.

The thing is we don't need to Unit Test repository classes because mostly they delegate the database query to EF or NHibernate so some sort of integration tests are good for them.